# How to evaluate the height of a ybar to change color of label accordingly

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

## Problem

I want to change the color of a `node near coords` label depending on the height of the bar it lies on. That is, if the label is outside the bar I want to put a color that is different from the background, and if it is inside the bar to use a different color.

## Code

For example

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{%
  every node near coord/.style={
    check for zero/.code={ % If meta=0, make the node a coordinate (which doesn't have text)
      \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{
          \pgfkeys{/tikz/coordinate}
      }{}
    },
    check for zero, color=white, text opacity=1, font=\footnotesize, inner 
    ysep=1pt,
  },%
  % Bottom nodes 
  calculate full offset/.code={
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{((\pgfplotspointmeta-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})*10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength}
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  },%
  nodes near coords bottom/.style={
      every node near coord/.append style={
          /pgfplots/calculate full offset,
          yshift=-\testmacro,
          anchor=south
          %rotate=90, anchor=west%I need the rotate text here and not in the 
          %general style, as the ybar redefines the style
      }
  },%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  ybar, 
  nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
  nodes near coords bottom,
  enlarge y limits=false,
  ymin=0,
]
\addplot plot coordinates {(1,1) (2,51) (3,5) (4,3) (5,6) (6,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you see, the `1` is in between the height of the bar. So, I need to, somehow, access and test the height of the bar it lies on to change the color from `white` to `black`, for example.

## Question

How can I do that? Is there any option in `pgfplots` to access that information?

Answer (score 3):

This adds the `color code` key to test if the y value is less than 2; if so, the label is black; otherwise, the label is white.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{%
  every node near coord/.style={
    check for zero/.code={ % If meta=0, make the node a coordinate (which doesn't have text)
      \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{
          \pgfkeys{/tikz/coordinate}
      }{}
    },
    color code/.code={%Added code to set node color based on the height of the bar
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta-2}%will be negative if less than 2
        \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{-}{\pgfkeys{/tikz/color=black}}{\pgfkeys{/tikz/color=white}}},
    check for zero, color code, text opacity=1, font=\footnotesize, inner 
    ysep=1pt,
  },%
  % Bottom nodes 
  calculate full offset/.code={
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{((\pgfplotspointmeta-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})*10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength}
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  },%
  nodes near coords bottom/.style={
      every node near coord/.append style={
          /pgfplots/calculate full offset,
          yshift=-\testmacro,
          anchor=south
          %rotate=90, anchor=west%I need the rotate text here and not in the 
          %general style, as the ybar redefines the style
      }
  },%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  ybar, 
  nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
  nodes near coords bottom,
  enlarge y limits=false,
  ymin=0,
]
\addplot plot coordinates {(1,1) (2,51) (3,5) (4,3) (5,6) (6,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I was looking for a more general solution. Do you know how to access the height of the plot instead of looking at the value?