# Invoke PGF/FPU inside \pgfplotsset

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, fpu

I am facing a problem when trying to get the maximum value of a table with large numbers.
Here are two small MWE:

With this simple comparison, I get the larger of two numbers:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{100000}
\pgfmathsetmacro\b{200000}
\pgfmathparse{\a > \b ? \a: \b}
\edef\c{\pgfmathresult}
Larger number: \c
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\end{document}
```

However, if I put that comparison inside a `.code` handler in `\pgfplotsset`, I get a 'Dimension too large' Error.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{%
    test/.code={%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\a{100000}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{200000}
        \pgfmathparse{\a > \b ? \a: \b}
        \edef\c{\pgfmathresult}
        Larger number: \c
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    }
}

\begin{axis}[test]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems like the invocation of the fpu library has not worked here. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Guess it's because `pgfplots` filtered out `/pgf/<key>` keys in processing optional argument of `axis` environment (only `/pgfplots` and `/tikz` keys are allowed), thus `\pgfset{/pgf/fpu}` does nothing. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Interestingly, in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282852/how-to-evaluate-the-height-of-a-ybar-to-change-color-of-label-accordingly) they also invoked the fpu library from pgfplotsset. What I want to achieve, is to make some calculations from my input table, to determine the limit values of my `z axis` for a 3d bar histogram.

Comment: In that post, the `fpu=true` is used in style `every node near coord`, which is not used right in the optional argument of `axis` env, but in a latter time at which the `/pgf` keys are not filtered out. It's the opt-arg of `axis` env that's special.

Answer (score 0):

A direct workaround is just doing the calculation before `axiz` environment, possibly inside the outer `tikzpicture` environment.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}
% \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}
% \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\c{max(100000,200000)}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  
  \begin{axis}[ymax=\c/10000] % ymax is set to 20 successfully
    \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

If the calculation result (`\c` in example above) is used only once,  simply use

```tex
\begin{axis}[ymax={max(100000,200000)/10000}]
```